# Text replacement before macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have to edit the content of `PORTXbits.RXY` with X and Y that can vary (known at compilation but vary in the code). I would like to be able to write someting like `PORTBIT(X, Y) = 1;` with X defined unsing a define to only have to change it one time in the code.

I have written

```
#define X A
#define Z B
#define PORTBIT(X, Y) PORT ##Xbits.R ##X ##Y

PORTBIT(X, 0) = 1; // => PORTXbits.RX0 = 1; I want PORTAbits.RA0 = 1;
PORTBIT(Z, 0) = 1; // => PORTZbits.RZ0 = 1;
```

thats works BUT `X` is never replaced because the preprocessor replace as it go trough the code, so PORTBIT is replaced before.

Is there anyway to accomplish this replacement before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xbits` is token `Xbits`. You have to join `X` with `bits` if you want `X` to be replaced.

```
#define PORTBIT(X, Y)    PORT##X##bits.R##X##Y
```

The arguments are *replaced*, not expanded, when under operator `##`. You have to do another pass to let them expand - for example to make `Z` expand to `B`.

```
#define PORTBIT_IN(X, Y)    PORT##X##bits.R##X##Y
#define PORTBIT(X, Y)       PORTBIT_IN(X, Y)
```

Comment: Extremely clear, thanks a lot ! Will a give +1 as sonn as I can

Answer (score 0):

You need to catenate `X` also to whatever comes later, as in:

```
#define PORTBIT(X, Y) PORT ## X ## bits.R ## X ## Y
PORTBIT(A,0); /* -> PORTAbits.RA0 */
```

a good way to test it is to run it through the preprocessor

```
$ cpp <file.c | less
...
PORTAbits.RA0;
...
$ _
```

IMHO, to learn how the preprocessor works this exercise is fine... but don't try this in production code that scans your code searching for identifiers.